# SQL Injection Prevention Method

Tags: sql, postgresql, security, sql-injection

If I wrapped an explain around a sql statement i.e.

`explain ( [arbitrary sql string] )`

I should be able to prevent injections of `create`, `drop`, `truncate`, `delete` commands correct?

I've only tried this on postgres and it seems to work, but I don't know if there's a corner case that I forgot.

Comment: Try this text - http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/06/detecting-postgres-sql-injection.html - basically safest way is to use values from input controls only as values pro prepared statements. Or to wrap them for statement using `quote_literal` or `quote_nullable`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope. It won't work. You could still end up with something like this:

```
Explain( select columns from table where value = '');injected sql here --)
```

All you've done is make the attacker do just a very little bit of extra work to figure out they also need the `)` character in addition to the usual single quote.

If you want to prevent Sql injection, make sure you **always** use parameterized queries.

Comment: To give the context of the question. is there a way for me to validate arbitrary SQL against a schema without being vulnerable to injection

Comment: @EricYang, you should never execute unvetted, arbitrary SQL from an untrusted source.

Answer (score 3):

You need in general :

1/ Validate the data you need with a whitelist approach. Do not blacklist characters or other things

2/ use Parametrized queries

3/ Don't use dynamic query anytime